# What is the purpose of this rubber tab on the leading edge of the window?

Tags: window, identify-this, rubber

Last week I parked next to a much older vehicle at work, and I saw this:

[image: picture of old car window with rubber tab sticking out]

It reminded me of my old 1995 Geo Prizm, which also had a tab like this on the leading edge of the front windows. However, I have not seen such a protuberance on any modern vehicle.

What is the purpose of this item, and why is it apparently no longer necessary?

Comment: I think they bring the window into alignment when rolling it up at higher speeds.

Comment: I don't really have the time to research here at work, but I could swear this is a duplicate of another question asked many moons ago ... Maybe I can find it later.

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11375/what-is-the-small-plastic-dimple-found-on-some-front-doors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the small plastic dimple found on some front doors?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11375/what-is-the-small-plastic-dimple-found-on-some-front-doors)

Comment: @PhilG - Thanks for the assist ... I knew I'd seen the question out there before.

Answer (score -1):

As noted by @ Tim Nevins ; It guides the window. This is when there is no metal window frame at the top of the door and it is essentially a bare piece of glass that has limited guidance by the door.I think typical of less expensive cars but from limited observation.

Comment: "... no metal frame at the top of the door" is not correct. There are many examples - including my old Prizm, and a linked question - where there are large window frames.